# How can I Create an array with N zeros?

Tags: javascript

I want an array with N zeroes, like

```
[0,0,0,0...0]
```

I could do a for-loop and push them all, but is there a nicer way?

```
var x = []
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x.push(0)
};
```

Comment: The version you've shown probably offers the best performance.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Int8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array):

```
var x = new Int8Array(100)
# x now is filled with 0s and is of size 100
```

> The **Int8Array** typed array represents an array of twos-complement `8`-bit signed integers. The contents are initialized to `0`.

See also: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-49

Comment: You should add the new operator: var x = new Int8Array(100);

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez thanks! :) fixed